# How can one create a robot which respondes to input following a flowchart?

Tags: microcontroller

What are the most basic skills and components needed for creating a robot which gets two "yes" or "no" inputs with two push buttons, and goes down the defined flowchart and plays the relevant audio file each time it gets an input.

a flowchart like this:

```
____question 1_____________
|                         |
Yes                       No
|                         |
question 2___             question 3______
|           |             |              |
Yes         No            Yes            No
|           |             |              |
question 4  question 5    question 6     question 7
...
```

Comment: Hi Drust, Welcome to the robotics Stack Exchange. This is quite a broad question, and so is a little difficult to answer. Also, it's hard to see how it relates to robots; it seems more like an electronics question. Perhaps you can add some more detail and clarification about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet you're right, now that I think of it, it's seems it's more of an electronic question and yes I think I should be more specific in the quesiton, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would really be more of a programming problem than an actual robotics one. Either way, you would be programming this logic into it anyways. Basically, it would be a series of if/then statements that would get you to where you need to go.

Example:

```
//ask question here and get input (button press)
if( the button pressed was yes){

    //ask the next question, and get more input, repeat this process
}else{
    //do the other button's side of the flowchart
}
```

Using this method, you would be able to setup your flowchart's logic flow perfectly.

Alternately, you could also use a switch/case, to get the same effect.

If you have no idea what I'm talking about, then be more specific as to how you are controlling this thing

Comment: thanks, so I need two buttons, a loudspeaker, and a microcontroller and some programming for the microcontroller and it's done?

Comment: Yes, the micro controller is what controls everything, and that micro controller is programmable in some way. You would do all of your logic programming with the controller. If you do not know what microcontroller to use, I would recommend an Arduinio Uno. They are easy to use and program, and have alot of support/documentation/wide user base